Scatter plot on a region of the sky with a circle
I am trying to do a scatter plot of a few data points on a region of the sky and then add a circle to the plot. Note, that I don't want a plot of the full sky, just of the region around the data points. The coordinates of the data points in degrees are:
ra = np.array([248.3, 249.8, 250.2, 250.5, 250.5])
dec = np.array([68.8, 67.7, 65.7, 72.2, 63.3])

The centre of the circle should be at
ra1 = 270
dec1= 66

It seems the packages for that (because we need to account for the curvature of the sky!) would be astropy and regions. But I just can't make it work. This post here is almost what I want to achieve, but it works with only one point and I don't see how to add more points. Thx for advice!

Using the linked example you could do:
import numpy as np
import astropy.units as u
from gammapy.maps import RegionGeom
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from regions import CircleSkyRegion, PointSkyRegion

ra = np.array([248.3, 249.8, 250.2, 250.5, 250.5])
dec = np.array([68.8, 67.7, 65.7, 72.2, 63.3])
ra1, dec1 = 270, 66

region = RegionGeom(CircleSkyRegion(SkyCoord(ra=ra1, dec=dec1, unit='deg'), 10 * u.deg))
centers = [SkyCoord(ra=ra, dec=dec, unit='deg') for ra, dec in zip(ra, dec)]
points = [RegionGeom(PointSkyRegion(center=center)) for center in centers]

ax = region.plot_region()
for point in points:
    point.plot_region(ax=ax, facecolor="black", edgecolor="black",
        kwargs_point={"fillstyle": "full", "marker": "o"}
    )
ax.grid()



Thanks, this works! But I hoped there would be a more elegant way to plot the points than looping through the points.
